# Converting WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere to a lat long raster

Tags: gdal, gdalwarp, wgs84

I have a dataset I downloaded with the following attributes shown with `gdalinfo`. How can I convert it to a lat long based raster file?

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: d2wesri.tif
Size is 1300, 900
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Open of /home/default_user/.conda/envs/user/share/proj failed
proj_create_from_database: Open of /home/default_user/.conda/envs/user/share/proj failed
Coordinate System is:
ENGCRS["WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere",
    EDATUM[""],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
    ID["EPSG",3857]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 1,2
Origin = (-20037507.067200001329184,19302890.717915385961533)
Pixel Size = (30826.923076923078042,-30826.923076923078042)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-20037507.067,19302890.718)
Lower Left  (-20037507.067,-8441340.051)
Upper Right (20037492.933,19302890.718)
Lower Right (20037492.933,-8441340.051)
Center      (      -7.067, 5430775.333)
Band 1 Block=128x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Gray
  Metadata:
    SourceBandIndex=0
```

I would like a lat long based raster file that would look like this:

```
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["latitude",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["longitude",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
Data axis to CRS axis mapping: 2,1
Origin = (-179.999988908250998,83.329027777777995)
Pixel Size = (0.005208333332500,-0.005208372298073)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  DataType=Generic
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-179.9999889,  83.3290278) (179d59'59.96"W, 83d19'44.50"N)
Lower Left  (-179.9999889, -55.9063889) (179d59'59.96"W, 55d54'23.00"S)
Upper Right ( 180.0000110,  83.3290278) (180d 0' 0.04"E, 83d19'44.50"N)
Lower Right ( 180.0000110, -55.9063889) (180d 0' 0.04"E, 55d54'23.00"S)
Center      (   0.0000111,  13.7113195) (  0d 0' 0.04"E, 13d42'40.75"N)
```

I tried using `gdalwarp -of GTiff -s_srs epsg:3857 -t_srs epsg:4326 d2wesri.tif d2wesri_warped.tif`
to convert the file, but it fails with

```
ERROR 1: PROJ: proj_create_from_database: Open of /home/default_user/.conda/envs/user/share/proj failed
ERROR 1: Translating source or target SRS failed:
epsg:3857
```

I uploaded a sample file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BmbxVjUzFbHoYb7HAs8K-07J8bTZvL84/view?usp=sharing) as well.

Comment: Works for me. Sounds like your conda env is either not activated or not working correctly.

Comment: Oh interesting. On this same dataset? All my other gdal commands are working and gdalwarp with other files is working as well for me.

Comment: Yes, same dataset, same command.  I used an old GDAL though (GDAL 2.2.3, released 2017/11/20), perhaps you're using GDAL 3x with the new PROJ. I vaguely remember some people having issues with that.